# jquery fadein & fadeout not working on iphone and ipad

Tags: jquery, ipad

On a standard desktop browser the following code all works fine:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var leftToBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();
  var distanceFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if( distanceFromTop > 800 
        && !$("#content-about").is(":visible") 
        && leftToBottom > 2000) {
    $("#content-about").fadeIn("slow");
  }else{
    if( $("#content-about").is(":visible") 
          && (distanceFromTop < 800 
          || leftToBottom     < 2000 ) ){
      $("#content-about").fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
</script>
```

Where the div tag appears and disappears as the browser scrolls up or down. On a ipad/iphone it works intermittently where sometimes it appears then you go back and it totally disappears!! The css for the div tag is set as follows:

```
#content-about {
width: 900px;
height:750px;
top:1200px;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the code that would not work. But you can check logically its really calling these methods by adding messages to the `console`.

Comment: use jQuery Mobile Animations for iphone: http://jquerymobile.com/

and use `{ transition: "turn" }`

Comment: sorry you are helping the uneducated here!! Talha can you tell me what you mean by 'But you can check logically its really calling these methods by adding messages to the console.' Basically want this one script to work across all devices and avoid alternative builds if I can.